# How to create executable WAR or JAR in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote a simple HELLOWORLD Springboot/thymeleaf project in eclipse and I can run it.
Then I tried to create a single executable war (or jar) file, but it is not possible. What I need is a single executable Jar or war file that I use as a executable (runnable) file on my computer without using eclipse.

[Export as a War](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0lyS.png)

[Export as a Jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TYuG.jpg)

application class:

```
package com.example.handlingformsubmission;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HandlingFormSubmissionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HandlingFormSubmissionApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The Controller ->

```
package com.example.handlingformsubmission;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        return "result";
    }

}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>handling-form-submission</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>handling-form-submission</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

http file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend starting with a generated project from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io). It'll make sure you have all the necessary bits configured to build a runnable jar with a Web project (just select "Web" and "Thymeleaf"). (If that's what you _did_ here, then you haven't shown a main class.)

Comment: I forgot to add application class. I just did. I can run the program in eclipse. I need to export it as a executable jar or war.

Comment: In this case, plain ordinary `mvn package` should do what you need. Please explain in detail how this "is not possible".

Comment: Please check the pictures. I click right on the project and choose EXPORT. Then I tried both option: As a WAR file or as a runnable jar. But for the first one I need a web Project file and for the jar I need a Configuration file and I have no idea what they are.

Comment: Please go to the folder where your pom.xml file is present (not within eclipse, go to file explorer) and run mvn package. Refer: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/how-to-package-spring-boot-application-to-jar-and-war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

1- Add this code in pom file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

2- Then run the project as a MAVEN BUILD.

3- write "package" in goals field.

4- click run.

Comment: Your question said that you _did_ have this in your POM.